Is it possible to enable markdown parsing of links in comments on questions and answers?
In the body of a question or answer, I can e.g. write [Shor94] to include a reference to a paper, and similarly I can link to other resources — but in comments I seemingly cannot, as I recently discovered when answering Mark Spinelli's comment on this answer. It is not very nice to have complete URLs and DOIs printed out in the comments section on posts.

Is there a good reason for why markdown formatting for links in comments is not supported?
(I do not know if this is the right forum to ask this question. If not, please let me know where I should ask it.)

If markdown formatting for links in comments could be supported in the future, I think the URL itself should not be included in the character count for the comment.
It seems inappropriate to limit the comment space for a user simply because the DOI or URL that the user wishes to reference is unwieldy. If anything, I think referencing relevant sources and resources should be encouraged.



I took the liberty of editing your comment on that post you linked to remove the spaces to get the markdown formatter to recognise your links - in short, [name](URL) will work, while [name] (URL) won't

@Mithrandir24601 Thanks. I originally tried to do [E23p], i.e. to place E23p within brackets, since I laster refer to [E23p] again, but that seemed not to work. Now it looks a bit odd, with E23p without brackets first and then with, but maybe that cannot be helped.

(The above comment illustrates the problem with the parsing. That kind of link works in the body, but not in comments, for some reason. As you state in your answer.)

Ahh, I see! - glS managed to fix that bit, presumably by escaping the brackets, so hopefully you're happy with it now?

Yes, now I at least know how to handle this. Thanks to both of you for helping out! I accepted the answer from glS now, but really the answers complement each other.

More specifically about the double-bracket issue: you can escape the inner square brackets to get links with brackets, eg [test] works, which you achieve with [\[test\]](link). This has also been reported on mother meta, see eg here. I edited in the square brackets in the comment at issue, as that's what you originally wanted if I understand correctly.
Perhaps somewhat more straightforwardly, you can also have only the inside of the brackets be a link: [test], which you get with [[test](link)].
Though it looks like this latter method actually linkifies the first but not the second bracket. Go figure.

comment to show this works: [test with brackets part of the link], and [test with brackets outside of the link].

Thanks! Yes, this is what I wanted. Excellent. Okay, so I have to escape the brackets in comments, but not in the body of questions or answers. Interesting. It seems that different parsing routines are being used, that behave differently.

Some subset of markdown is allowed in comments, described in more detail in this meta SE post and this section of the help centre.
Specifically in terms of links, functionality is less than in a full question or answer: only 'basic' links work, in the form [described in the help centre](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) - spaces between the different brackets i.e. [name](URL) will work, while [name] (URL) won't.
As for why it only works this way, I don't know exactly but would assume issues such as 'loading times' become involved somewhere. I do believe that comments are limited in character length due to the memory given to its entry in the relevant database.

I will accept this answer. In my case it was the double-brackets that did not work; I then deliberately added the spaces to resolve the issue.
